# How can I get the calling ViewController from the supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor method in AppDelegate?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I've added a feature in my app which is in Swift 4, which allows a view to orientate to landscape or portrait as it displays a chart. I've created two separate views for each orientation and I've created the logic to handle the process. It works okay except for one minor niggle which I can solve if I can determine the calling ViewController. I've tried using

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController
```

Which has not proved to be accurate. I've checked the parameters of both application and window without any success. Is this possible to do or do I need to rely on a global variable instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app delegate returns a bitmask that indicates the "maximum set" of orientations supported by the complete app, regardless of which view controller is currently presented.

The presented, concrete view controller is also asked in addition (`supportedInterfaceOrientations`)  and returns its own supported orientations.

In the end, both return values will be intersected to get the current supported orientations.

If I remember correctly, both values have to agree in at least one orientation. If e.g. the app delegate says it only supports "portrait (up)", but the view controller only supports "landscape left", your app will crash (or do something even worse)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Andreas, I'm aware of how the method handles the orientations, it is the calling ViewController that I need to identify and I'm starting to think that this isn't possible and that a global variable will be better

Comment: I don't quite get it. The viewcontroller is not calling anything, it is been called by the framework. Or do you have some homemade view controller containment?

Comment: Changing the orientation in any of the app's ViewControllers results in supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor  being called. My app has 18 ViewControllers and I just need to be able know in the method supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor when the ViewController is the one which needs landscape orientation, so I need to be to check the ViewController which is current.

Comment: As a wrote in my answer, the AppDelegate's method `supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor` returns the _union_ of all possible supported interface orientations of _all_ your view controllers. It should not care which view controller is currently being presented. The individual "top" view controller returns _his_ supported orientations. So why do you want to know which is the presented one, since it's function `supportedInterfaceOrientations` will be called by the framework?

Comment: I really appreciate your reply but you don't seem to grasp what I'm trying to do. It seems that from your comments I'm best advised to use a global variable to determine which controller is in play and not try and second guess from within the method

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the topmost viewController of your app like this:

```
func topViewController() -> UIViewController {
        let controller = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        if let presentedVC = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return presentedVC
        }
        return controller!
    }
```

Comment: I could not get this to work, it always threw an error at return controller as it was a nil value

Answer (score 0):

Getting to the topViewController is dependent on the configuration of the views. Using .isKind(of: VC) helps you return the appropriate ViewController based on whatever view hierarchy you may be using:

```
private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
    if (rootViewController == nil) { return nil }
    if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
}
```